# Binding a property in extjs4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I just create my component, based in 'Ext.form.field.Trigger' with this config params:

```
config: {
    selectedId: 0,
    selectedRecord: null,
    searchControl: '',
    displayField: '',
    autoSearch: true
},
```

How can I bind the "selectedId" variable to be send to server as the value of a field of this kind ?

For example:

I have a field in my table: brand_id.

I have in my form, my custom control that needs to send the id of a brand record (just like combobox). This id is in the "selectedId" variable.

Comment: Can you be a bit clear on what u want to do? You mean to say that when ever you do a form submit you want to send additional params like selectedID etc etc?

Comment: Hi Patton, I made an update to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override the `getValue()` method of the custom `triggerfield` component that you built. Depending on the way the submit method is called, the predefined methods on the `form` use the `getValue() or`getRawValue()` methods during submission.

If you read the `getValue()` [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-method-getValue) for the triggerfield, you'll see the following documentation:

> Returns the current data value of the field. The type of value
>   returned is particular to the type of the particular field (e.g. a
>   Date object for Ext.form.field.Date), as the result of calling
>   rawToValue on the field's processed String value. To return the raw
>   String value, see getRawValue.

So override the `getValue()` method and return whatever you want sent to the server. By default the getValue() will return the underlying html `input` field's value property.

Comment: So, what´s the property that represents the text in the component ?

Comment: Since, in the end, extjs will actually generate html, it'll be whatever the `<input type="...">`'s value property.